# Shared drive activity not sending notification

Tags: google-drive-api, google-workspace, google-drive-shared-drive, google-apps-activity, google-drive-activity-api

The troubles with receiving notifications about changes being made on specified shared drive by users other than me.

Steps:
First i'm getting new startPageToken:

`https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/changes/startPageToken?driveId=<drive_id>&supportsAllDrives=true`

Then i'm setting up changes watch:

`https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/changes/watch?pageToken=<page_token_from_above>&includeItemsFromAllDrives=true&supportsAllDrives=true&driveId=<drive_id>&spaces=drive&includeSubscribed=true&includeDeleted=true'`

```
{
  "address": "<webhook.site webhook listener>",
  "kind": "api#channel",
  "type": "web_hook",
  "id": "<uuid_generated_by_me>"
}
```

After that i'm receiving sync message. When user any user except me will do any changes on shared drive i'm not receiving webhook notification. But when i'm using page token on list endpoint `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/changes` i'm seeing those changes.

Access token used to on `changes/watch` has Manager permission and `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` role , same for other users who are adding files.